# Android TabLayout on the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I have this generated XML code when I started a new Tabbed Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="eis1617.muellerkimmeyer.app.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

How exactly must I change it, that the tab bar will be placed on the bottom of the screen? On the TabLayout Tag I already tried to add **android:layout_gravity="bottom"**, but it didnt change anything.

Comment: You are doing it wrong? do you mean bottom menu?

Comment: What you mean? I want the tab bar placed on the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Added answer for bottom menu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I achieved it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="in.mylo.pregnancy.baby.app.FAB">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
       android:id="@+id/viewPagerHome"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_above="@+id/bottomNavigation" />

   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="bottom"
       android:background="@android:color/white"
       android:elevation="80dp">

     <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
          android:id="@+id/bottomNavigation"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="56dp"
          android:clickable="true"
          app:tabBackground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
          app:tabGravity="fill"
          app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
          app:tabMode="fixed"
          app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/black" />

   </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Would be nice to know what I must change on my code. Because I want to keep all elements. In your code the toolbar is missing for example.

Comment: @Nono I've edited my answer, check now. Remove the TabLayout from AppBarLayout; create new AppBarLayout below ViewPager and add TabLayout there.

Answer (score 1):

**Layout**
Dont use tab menu, instead add the new material bottom navigation view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpagerhome"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/menucolor"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/menucolor"
            app:menu="@menu/bottommenu"/>
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**menu to be used at the bottom**
as its a bottom menu, its required an menu to be inflated

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_order"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/orders"
        android:title="My Orders"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_account"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/account"
        android:title="My Account"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_logout"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/account"
        android:title="Logout"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

**In your Activity class**
initialize your declare your bottom menu and implement the listner,

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation); 

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                    new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

                            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                                case R.id.action_order:
                                    // your fragment or activity code here
                                    break;
                                case R.id.action_account:
                                    // your fragment or activity code here
                                    break;
                                case R.id.action_logout:
                                    break;
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
        }
```

Done!
Hope this helps.